# How to access PGraphics pixels in p5.js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm trying to access pixels from a PGraphics instance in p5.js but even after calling `loadPixels()` the array is empty.

Here's what I've tried:

```
var buffer;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(100,100);
  pixelDensity(1);

  buffer = createGraphics(100,100);
  buffer.background(128);
}

function draw() {
  image(buffer,0,0);
}

function mouseDragged(){
  buffer.ellipse(mouseX,mouseY,3,3);
  buffer.loadPixels();
  console.log(buffer.pixels);//expecint pixels array, getting empty array
}
```

Is it possible to access pixels in PGraphics with p5.js ? If so, how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug: https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1403

Other related bugs [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/995) and [here](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/issues/1311).

It is fixed with the latest version (Version 0.5.3 from August 17, 2016).

If you're using the p5.js editor like me, then apparently that uses an old version of the library. You can download the latest version and copy it into your sketch folder. That seems to be persisting between runs of the editor, which is slightly scary, but maybe some magic is going on behind the scenes.

Anyway, your code works as expected after updating to the latest version.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Kevin! Should've checked the issues list.
I am indeed using the p5.js editor as well. I've update the project folder, but also the libraries in the editor as well (```p5.app/Contents/Resources/app.nw/mode_assets/p5/empty_project/```)

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza Happy to help! What's weird is that for me (on Windows 10) I just replaced the `p5.js` file in the project folder, but now that seems to be persisting after I shutdown the editor and open it again. Maybe it secretly copies the file into the editor library location. That doesn't impact you at all, just thought it was weird. Happy coding!